# Поправка в сводке профиля

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Обратил внимание на то, что в профиле участников неверно написано над зелёной шкалой. Числа там отображают не **баллы рейтинга**, а количество голосов. Когда кто-то отмечает ответ, то на этой шкале прибавляется не 10 баллов, а 1 (то есть один голос).
Предлагаю так и написать: 757/1000 **голосов**. Или же (если оставить "баллов") всё умножить на 10.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы исправил — проверьте, пожалуйста, через некоторое время. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! Пока ничего не изменилось. А насчёт неразрывного пробела так и не ответили. Не пришло уведомление о комментарии без имени?

Comment: Пожалуйста, задайте отдельный вопрос :) @АлександрСтрелец

Comment: Aer, странно как-то... Изменение произошло выборочно: из 24 первых участников у 12 поменялось на "голосов", а у 12 осталось "баллов".

Comment: Aer, пока так и остаётся...